# How to pass a value in src="@url.content" using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
<script>

    var Details = function (Id, username, Empname, UserType, Address, Gender, Mob, image) {
        $("#hiddenEmployeeId").val(Id);
        $("#EditModal").modal("show");
        $("#susertype").html(UserType);
        $("#saddress").html(Address);
        $("#sgender").html(Gender);
        $("#smob").html(Mob);
        $("#suname").html(Empname);
        $("#sename").html(username);
    }


</script>
```

Getting value from from a image variable form above that script

```
<img src="@Url.content("")" />
```

i have to place in this img

Comment: i have to add in <img src="@Url.content("")>

Comment: it's completely unclear what you wants to achieve can you pleae elaborate more

Comment: what i understand from this is you want to set image's SRC right? if yes just give `class` or `Id` to `img` and than set attribute value using `class` or `ID`

Comment: see in function i am getting one image path that path should be passed in <img src="@Url.content("")" /> this htm code by using script

Answer (score 0):

you can not use javascript variable directly. so you have to manage your image path like below.

```
<script>    
    var Details = function (Id, username, Empname, UserType, Address, Gender, Mob, image) {
        $("#hiddenEmployeeId").val(Id);
        $("#EditModal").modal("show");
        $("#susertype").html(UserType);
        $("#saddress").html(Address);
        $("#sgender").html(Gender);
        $("#smob").html(Mob);
        $("#suname").html(Empname);
        $("#sename").html(username);
        $("#image").attr("src",@Url.content("~/")image);
    }
</script>
<img id="image" />
```

Comment: `.html()` will replace image html which doesn't make any sense he wants to set `attribute` of image

Answer (score 0):

give `class` or `Id` to `img` as below

```
<img class="img" src="@Url.content("")" />
```

and than set attribute value using `class` or `ID` as below

```
$(".img").attr("src","xyz");
```

For this example i have used `class` you can also use `ID` for the same

Comment: problem is not with how to access img, problem is how to access with `@Url.content("")`

Answer (score 0):

I kind of have the similar problem you're facing: I have JavaScript code that runs after page loads to bring a list of items, and each might have a thumbnail which is stored under `wwwroot` (asp.net core 2.0 speaking).

I can't just build `<a href="THE_PATH" download />` whose path is coming from the JavaScript code because for security reasons on some modern browsers, i.e, you will get an error **Not allowed to load local resource**.

Ideally you (wish you) can use `<a href="@Url.Content("THE_PATH")" />` to get the content from the Server and the problem solved. But you can't inject the PATH into `@Url.Content()` because `@Url.Content()` executes first on the server side and it would be too late when you inject the path from the JavaScript code.

### Option 1

Store the image/thumbnail as a record in the database with an identifier (GUID works the best), and on the page build a link that corresponds an `Controller` and an `Action` that fetches the image by id and returns its content as file result, i.e., `return File();`.

### Option 2 (with ASP.NET Core 2.0)

Store the image/thumbnail physically in your web root folder, i.e., `wwwroot/images` and enable static file by putting `app.UseStaticFiles()` on the `Configure()` method in `Startup.cs`.

Then you can build your image with your JavaScript variable like

```
<img src="{{ SOME_JS_VARIABLE_THAT_HOLDS_RELATIVE_PATH }}" />
```

The relative path might look like something like `/uploads/2018/1/1/pic1.jpg`, without the content root.